# Does this function built in in Python?

Tags: python, function, methods

considering the following code is there a function that take the odd indexed values and put it in array and the even to put it in another array then relate two arrays elements to each other in order to do some processing on it.

hm to run:  ")
        if IN == '1':

```
 PN = input("   Enter each process time following by its arrival time separated by comma:")
        Ptimes = [] 
        Atimes = []
```

Comment: How is the code you have posted related to your question, if at all?

Comment: it's a part of the code that i am asking about sorry i will delete the extra useless code thanks for your note

Comment: What does `hm to run: ")` mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values at even indices like this:

```
PN[::2]  # Start at 0, jump every two so 0, 2 etc.
```

and the ones at odd like this:

```
PN[1::2]  # Start at 1, jump every two so 1, 3 etc.
```

Comment: does comma considered as an array element i mean i want to pass the comma and ignore it consider it an integer array or do  i have to tell the user to separate numbers by a space instead of comma?

Comment: @user3541982 I would just do it with spaces, and then just `split()` the input to get a list out of it.

Comment: @AlexThornton that gets *the items **at** even/odd indices*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't understand, he said in the question he wanted to 'get the odd-indexed values'.

Comment: @AlexThornton yes, that is what you give, but your description is "get the even *indices*"

Comment: You can also split at commas with `"1,2".split(",")`. And if there are also spaces (not as separator), this will also strip each component: `s="1, 2,   3"; [x.strip() for x in s.split(",")]`

Comment: input ="1, 2, 3"; 
Ptimes = data[::2]   array for processes times
 Atimes = data[1::2] array for processes arrival times
so this code will consider 1 as the first element and 2 as the 2nd and so on ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are used to zero-based arrays (index 0, index 1):

```
even = data[::2]  # even indices: 0, 2, 4, ...
odds = data[1::2]  # odd indices: 1, 3, 5, ...
```

If prefer to think in one-based arrays (1st element, 2nd element):

```
odds = data[::2]  # 1st element, 3rd element, ...
even = data[1::2]  # 2nd element, 4th element, ...
```